# beginAnimations commitAnimations retain a view?

Tags: iphone, animation, retain

Suppose,(pseudo code)

```
view.alpha = 1.0;  
[beginAnimmations]  
[animationDuration = 1.0]
view.alpha = 0.0;
[commitAnimations]

[view removeFromSuperView];
```

When view is not retained anywhere else than its superview, hence [view removeFromSuperView] will make the view be dealloc-ed.

Is this safe? or How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *`view`* is not retained anywhere except by its *superview*, calling *`[view removeFromSuperView];`* is completely alright. And, as you've afraid, *`view`* will be released at that time. So, accessing it after the *`removeFromSuperView`* method call will not be safe.

You should be retaining *`view`* inorder to acces it even after you remove it from its superview.

**Changes in your code:**

You have to remove the *`view`* after the animation is over. Add the following lines while you create animation.

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(onAnimationStopped)];
```

The *onAnimationStopped* method,

```
- (void)onAnimationStopped {

    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: EmptyStack: then animation might not be seen correctly because it takes time, and view will be removed from superview before animation is finished?

Comment: You have to remove the view after the animation is over. See the edit.